# How to get name and gender from Facebook with Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the facebook c# sdk from my web application. When a user logs in via facebook I get a facebookid and a signedrequest. From this I would like to further retrieve the user's name and gender.

What I have so far is:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();

dynamic userDetails = fb.Get("me", new { fields = "name, gender" });
```

But what I can't figure out, is how I should set the user I want to lookup? I assume I will need to add the facebookid to the fb object somehow, before I call Get?

SOLUTION:

I found the answer. I have to set the accessToken before calling Get, like:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

dynamic userDetails = fb.Get("me", new { fields = "name, gender" });
```

The I get both name and gender back in userDetails.

Comment: me means the user that logged in. You can't get it from people that didn't log to your app

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer.